# transform a data row from mysql database to queue using jms producer in pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I want to read data from database and send each row of data to a queue. but in jms producer editor, I can choose just one column of each row as message field.

for example:
I have a table with (id,name,family,address,postcode) fields. I need to send each row of data to queue. But in jms producer editor, there is message field drop-down list which makes me to choose just one of above fields as message field(e.g. id or name or family ...)
How can I send whole row data to queue as one message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with JMS, but this situation calls for wrapping the data into a format that can be posted as the message.

I would use a JSON output step that turns every row into a JSON object (which goes into the message field). Configure it to output the value, not a file and set the Nr rows in a bloc to 1. On the fields tab, include all the fields you want to migrate.

XML output is also an option. Either way you may also need to escape any HTML/XML code on the compiled message and/or wrap it in a CDATA tag, depending on the contents of the row.

On the receiving side, the JSON can then be decoded back to fields. You will lose the exact data type and length metadata, that needs to be validated separately.